# D3 Zoom/Pan slow performance in React application with many datapoints

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I have a React application where  I've created a line chart with zoom and panning capabilities. Each data point in the chart is a separate react component.

The zoom gets triggered on the event *zoom* in the parent container, the `zoomTransform` is then used to calculate a new x- and y-scales called `zoomedXScale` and `zoomedYScale`. Once these new scales has been calculated the `useEffect` in the rendered components gets called and the x and y coordinates are updated.

The `zoom function` in the parent container:

```
const zoomed = d3
    .zoom()
    .extent([
      [0, 0],
      [width, height]
    ])
    .scaleExtent([MinZoom, MaxZoom]) // This control how much you can unzoom (x0.5) and zoom (x20)
    .translateExtent([
      [0, 0],
      [width, height]
    ])
    .on('zoom', (e: d3.D3ZoomEvent<SVGElement, unknown>) => {
      const zoomState = e.transform;
      setCurrentZoomState(zoomState);
    });
```

Example of `useEffect` in child component rendered in the svg:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const image = d3.select(ref.current);
    image
      .attr('x', zoomedXScale(price))
      .attr('y', zoomedYScale(price));
  }, [price, zoomedXScale, zoomedYScale, zoomTransform]);
```

The performance issue occurs when there is about 500-1000 components which gets rendered and each x- and y coordinates are updated for every zoom event, it gets very slow.

One possible solution i thought of after reading other related posts is to only render the points inside the current viewport. But I also wanted to know if there is a more efficient solution for updating coordinates for the different components in a React application using d3 with zoom and panning in a linechart.